Floating Point Precision Error or Algorithm Error?
I've implemented Fraction and Polynomial classes to simulate the mathematical operations that may be applied to them. The Fraction class was mainly implemented so that numbers like 2 / 3 will be represented as 2 / 3 rather than 0.666 only to be rounded off later.
Here's the Fraction class:
import math as m

class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, num, denom=1):
        
        if type(num) == float:
            num = floatToFraction(num)
        if type(denom) == float:
            denom = floatToFraction(denom)
        
        #num, denom must be of type int or Fraction
        
        if type(num) == int and type(denom) == int:   
        
            #catches zero divison
            if denom == 0:
                raise ZeroDivisionError()
                
            gcd = m.gcd(num, denom)
            
            #always in simplest form
            self.num = int(num / gcd)
            self.denom = int(denom / gcd)
            
        elif type(num) in [int, Fraction] and type(denom) in [int, Fraction]:
            
            #catches zero division
            if type(denom) == int:
                if denom == 0:
                    raise ZeroDivisionError()
            else:
                if denom.getNum() == 0:
                    raise ZeroDivisionError()
        
            new_f = num / denom
            self.num = new_f.getNum()
            self.denom = new_f.getDenom()
            
        else:
            raise TypeError('Constructor must receive inputs of type int, float or Fraction.')
            
        #sign-correction
        if self.num * self.denom > 0:
            self.num, self.denom = abs(self.num), abs(self.denom)
        else:
            self.num, self.denom = -1 * abs(self.num), abs(self.denom)
        
            
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.denom == 1:
            return f'{self.num}'
        return f'( {self.num} / {self.denom} )'
    
    def getNum(self):
        return self.num
    
    def getDenom(self):
        return self.denom
    
    def inverse(self):
        return Fraction(self.denom, self.num)
    
    def __add__(self, o_f):
        if type(o_f) == int:
            o_f = Fraction(o_f)
        return Fraction(self.num * o_f.getDenom() + self.denom * o_f.getNum(), self.denom * o_f.getDenom())
    
    def __radd__(self, o_f):
        return self + o_f
        
    def __sub__(self, o_f):
        return self + (o_f * -1)
    
    def __rsub__(self, o_f):
        return (self - o_f) * -1
    
    def __mul__(self, o_f):
        if type(o_f) == int:
            o_f = Fraction(o_f)
        return Fraction(self.num * o_f.getNum(), self.denom * o_f.getDenom())
    
    def __rmul__(self, o_f):
        return self * o_f
    
    def __truediv__(self, o_f):
        #define for operations between numbers and fractions
        if type(o_f) == int:
            o_f = Fraction(o_f)
        return self * o_f.inverse()
    
    def __rtruediv__(self, o_f):
        return Fraction(o_f) * self.inverse()
    
def floatToFraction(x):
    #only converts non-recurring decimals, CANNOT handle recurring decimals e.g. 0.333333
    d = 1
    while x % 1 != 0:
        x *= 10
        d *= 10
    return Fraction(int(x), int(d))

And here's the Polynomial class:
import numpy as np
from fraction import Fraction

class Polynomial:
    """
    NOTE:
        -> Constructor may accept a Polynomial, NumPy Array, List or Number. 
        -> Empty iterables will be replaced with an object of an equivalent type holding the number 0, for ease of computation.
    """
    
    def __init__(self, ipt=[]):
        #arr is the coefficient array describing the polynomial.
        if isinstance(ipt, Polynomial):
            #Creates a copy of an existing polynomial.
            ipt = ipt.getArr()
        elif type(ipt) == np.ndarray:
            if ipt.size == 0:
                ipt += np.array([Fraction(0)])
            ipt = np.array([n if isinstance(n, Fraction) else Fraction(float(n)) for n in ipt])
        elif type(ipt) == list:
            if len(ipt) == 0:
                ipt = [0]
            ipt = np.array([Fraction(n) for n in ipt])
        elif type(ipt) == int:
            ipt = np.array([Fraction(ipt)])
        else:
            raise TypeError('Constructor must be a Polynomial, NumPy Array, List or Number.')
        self.coef = np.array(ipt)
        self.dim = self.coef.size - 1
        
        
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.coef[idx]
        
    def __setitem__(self, n, coef):
        self.coef[n] = coef
        
    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = 0
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.index <= self.dim:
            coef = self[self.index]
            self.index += 1
            return coef
        raise StopIteration
    
    def __repr__(self):
        p_str = ''
        first = True
        for i in reversed(list(range(self.coef.size))):
            if self[i] != 0 or i == 0:
                p_str += ('+ ' if not first else '') + str(self[i]) + (f' * x^{str(i)} ' if i != 0 else '')
                first = False
            
        return p_str
    
    def getArr(self):
        return self.coef
    
    def getDim(self):
        return self.dim
    
    def _expand(self, n):
        #NOTE: Expansion will not affect the original array.
        k = n - self.dim
        exp_cpy = np.append(self.coef, np.zeros(k))
        return Polynomial(exp_cpy)
    
    """
    NOTE: Arithmetic operations accept constants and Polynomials only.
    """
        
    def __add__(self, P2):
        if not isinstance(P2, Polynomial):
            P2 = Polynomial([P2])
        if P2.getDim() < self.dim:
            return P2 + self
        else:
            return Polynomial(self._expand(P2.getDim()).getArr() + P2.getArr())
        
    def __sub__(self, P2):
        return self + (P2 * -1)
        
    def __mul__(self, P2):
        if type(P2) in [int, float, Fraction]:
            #Wraps it with a Polynomial object.
            P2 = Polynomial([P2])
        elif P2.getDim() < 0:
            P2 += Polynomial([0])
        product = Polynomial([])
        s1, s2 = self.dim + 1, P2.getDim() + 1
        for i in range(s2):
            temp = {}
            p_e = P2[i]
            for j in range(s1):
                temp[i+j] = self[j] * p_e #Single pass per element.
            new_p = Polynomial(np.zeros(max(temp.keys())+1))
            for k in temp:
                new_p[k] = temp[k]
            product += new_p
        return product
    
    def __rmul__(self, P2):
        return self * P2
    
    def compute(self, x):
        val = 0
        for i in range(self.dim + 1):
            val += self[i] * x ** i
        return val

I'm trying to implement a concept called perturbation theory in applied mathematics. The details of this aren't important, what I'm trying to compute are the coefficients for the polynomials that can be used to calculate the first x terms of k-powers. For example, for k=2, the sum of the first x terms of the series: 1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, ... , x^2 can be calculated using (1 / 3) * x^3 + (1 / 2) * x^2 + (1 / 6) * x. Such a polynomial exists for all k. I've written some code that computes the coefficients and memoizes the results as follows:
from fraction import Fraction

pn_bank = {}

def comb(x, y):
    #Computes xCy.
    v = Fraction(1)
    while y > 0:
        v *= Fraction(x, y)
        x -= 1
        y -= 1
    return v

def binom(n):
    #Computes the polynomial coefficients for (x + 1)^n.
    coef = []
    for i in range(n + 1):
        coef.append(comb(n, i))
    return coef

def perturb(n):
    c_arr = pn_bank.get(n)
    if c_arr:
        return c_arr
    coefs = binom(n + 1)
    coefs[n + 1] = 0
    rhs = Polynomial(1)
    for i in range(0, n):
        #Skips avoiding perturb(n + 1) and perturb(n) and triggering infinite recursion.
        rhs += perturb(i) * coefs[i]
    lhs = Polynomial(binom(n + 1)) - rhs
    lhs *= Fraction(1, coefs[n])
    return lhs

When I tried computing the coefficients for k=17 and upwards, the coefficients being computed are correct, but for some reason, the polynomial class's compute method isn't working correctly (at least that's where I think the problem lies). For example, the sum of the first 10 terms for k=17 is 19179318935377305 (according to Wolfram Alpha). According to a JavaScript for loop, it's 19179318935377304 and according to my code, it's 19179318935377305.666 (which is impossible since the sum of integers has to be an integer). I checked for k=18,19,etc. and this only occurs for the 9th term and onwards. Everything before is still accurate. Is there some floating-point round off error here? What might be going on here.
Here's the output as requested for k=0,1,2,...,19:
POWER: 0
POLYNOMIAL: 1 * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 2
SUM of 3rd term: 3
SUM of 10th term: 10
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 1
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 2 ) * x^2 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 3
SUM of 3rd term: 6
SUM of 10th term: 55
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 2
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 3 ) * x^3 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^2 + ( 1 / 6 ) * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 5
SUM of 3rd term: 14
SUM of 10th term: 385
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 3
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 4 ) * x^4 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^3 + ( 1 / 4 ) * x^2 + 0 * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 9
SUM of 3rd term: 36
SUM of 10th term: 3025
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 4
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 5 ) * x^5 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^4 + ( 1 / 3 ) * x^3 + 0 * x^2 + ( -1 / 30 ) * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 17
SUM of 3rd term: 98
SUM of 10th term: 25333
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 5
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 6 ) * x^6 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^5 + ( 5 / 12 ) * x^4 + 0 * x^3 + ( -1 / 12 ) * x^2 + 0 * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 33
SUM of 3rd term: 276
SUM of 10th term: 220825
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 6
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 7 ) * x^7 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^6 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^5 + 0 * x^4 + ( -1 / 6 ) * x^3 + 0 * x^2 + ( 1 / 42 ) * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 65
SUM of 3rd term: 794
SUM of 10th term: 1978405
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 7
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 8 ) * x^8 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^7 + ( 7 / 12 ) * x^6 + 0 * x^5 + ( -7 / 24 ) * x^4 + 0 * x^3 + ( 1 / 12 ) * x^2 + 0 * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 129
SUM of 3rd term: 2316
SUM of 10th term: 18080425
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 8
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 9 ) * x^9 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^8 + ( 2 / 3 ) * x^7 + 0 * x^6 + ( -7 / 15 ) * x^5 + 0 * x^4 + ( 2 / 9 ) * x^3 + 0 * x^2 + ( -1 / 30 ) * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 257
SUM of 3rd term: 6818
SUM of 10th term: 167731333
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 9
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 10 ) * x^10 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^9 + ( 3 / 4 ) * x^8 + 0 * x^7 + ( -7 / 10 ) * x^6 + 0 * x^5 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^4 + 0 * x^3 + ( -3 / 20 ) * x^2 + 0 * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 513
SUM of 3rd term: 20196
SUM of 10th term: 1574304985
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 10
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 11 ) * x^11 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^10 + ( 5 / 6 ) * x^9 + 0 * x^8 + -1 * x^7 + 0 * x^6 + 1 * x^5 + 0 * x^4 + ( -1 / 2 ) * x^3 + 0 * x^2 + ( 5 / 66 ) * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 1025
SUM of 3rd term: 60074
SUM of 10th term: 14914341925
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 11
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 12 ) * x^12 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^11 + ( 11 / 12 ) * x^10 + 0 * x^9 + ( -11 / 8 ) * x^8 + 0 * x^7 + ( 11 / 6 ) * x^6 + 0 * x^5 + ( -11 / 8 ) * x^4 + 0 * x^3 + ( 5 / 12 ) * x^2 + 0 * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 2049
SUM of 3rd term: 179196
SUM of 10th term: 142364319625
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 12
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 13 ) * x^13 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^12 + 1 * x^11 + 0 * x^10 + ( -11 / 6 ) * x^9 + 0 * x^8 + ( 22 / 7 ) * x^7 + 0 * x^6 + ( -33 / 10 ) * x^5 + 0 * x^4 + ( 5 / 3 ) * x^3 + 0 * x^2 + ( -691 / 2730 ) * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 4097
SUM of 3rd term: 535538
SUM of 10th term: 1367428536133
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 13
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 14 ) * x^14 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^13 + ( 13 / 12 ) * x^12 + 0 * x^11 + ( -143 / 60 ) * x^10 + 0 * x^9 + ( 143 / 28 ) * x^8 + 0 * x^7 + ( -143 / 20 ) * x^6 + 0 * x^5 + ( 65 / 12 ) * x^4 + 0 * x^3 + ( -691 / 420 ) * x^2 + 0 * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 8193
SUM of 3rd term: 1602516
SUM of 10th term: 13202860761145
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 14
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 15 ) * x^15 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^14 + ( 7 / 6 ) * x^13 + 0 * x^12 + ( -91 / 30 ) * x^11 + 0 * x^10 + ( 143 / 18 ) * x^9 + 0 * x^8 + ( -143 / 10 ) * x^7 + 0 * x^6 + ( 91 / 6 ) * x^5 + 0 * x^4 + ( -691 / 90 ) * x^3 + 0 * x^2 + ( 7 / 6 ) * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 16385
SUM of 3rd term: 4799354
SUM of 10th term: 128037802953445
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 15
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 16 ) * x^16 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^15 + ( 5 / 4 ) * x^14 + 0 * x^13 + ( -91 / 24 ) * x^12 + 0 * x^11 + ( 143 / 12 ) * x^10 + 0 * x^9 + ( -429 / 16 ) * x^8 + 0 * x^7 + ( 455 / 12 ) * x^6 + 0 * x^5 + ( -691 / 24 ) * x^4 + 0 * x^3 + ( 35 / 4 ) * x^2 + 0 * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 32769
SUM of 3rd term: 14381676
SUM of 10th term: 1246324856379625
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 16
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 17 ) * x^17 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^16 + ( 4 / 3 ) * x^15 + 0 * x^14 + ( -14 / 3 ) * x^13 + 0 * x^12 + ( 52 / 3 ) * x^11 + 0 * x^10 + ( -143 / 3 ) * x^9 + 0 * x^8 + ( 260 / 3 ) * x^7 + 0 * x^6 + ( -1382 / 15 ) * x^5 + 0 * x^4 + ( 140 / 3 ) * x^3 + 0 * x^2 + ( -3617 / 510 ) * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 65537
SUM of 3rd term: 43112258
SUM of 10th term: ( 206902004244165440 / 17 )
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 17
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 18 ) * x^18 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^17 + ( 17 / 12 ) * x^16 + 0 * x^15 + ( -17 / 3 ) * x^14 + 0 * x^13 + ( 221 / 9 ) * x^12 + 0 * x^11 + ( -2431 / 30 ) * x^10 + 0 * x^9 + ( 1105 / 6 ) * x^8 + 0 * x^7 + ( -11747 / 45 ) * x^6 + 0 * x^5 + ( 595 / 3 ) * x^4 + 0 * x^3 + ( -3617 / 60 ) * x^2 + 0 * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 131073
SUM of 3rd term: 129271236
SUM of 10th term: ( 1072613870418395776 / 9 )
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 18
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 19 ) * x^19 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^18 + ( 3 / 2 ) * x^17 + 0 * x^16 + ( -34 / 5 ) * x^15 + 0 * x^14 + 34 * x^13 + 0 * x^12 + ( -663 / 5 ) * x^11 + 0 * x^10 + ( 1105 / 3 ) * x^9 + 0 * x^8 + ( -23494 / 35 ) * x^7 + 0 * x^6 + 714 * x^5 + 0 * x^4 + ( -3617 / 10 ) * x^3 + 0 * x^2 + ( 43867 / 798 ) * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 262145
SUM of 3rd term: 387682634
SUM of 10th term: ( 22227014932144214016 / 19 )
-------------------------------------------------------

POWER: 19
POLYNOMIAL: ( 1 / 20 ) * x^20 + ( 1 / 2 ) * x^19 + ( 19 / 12 ) * x^18 + 0 * x^17 + ( -323 / 40 ) * x^16 + 0 * x^15 + ( 323 / 7 ) * x^14 + 0 * x^13 + ( -4199 / 20 ) * x^12 + 0 * x^11 + ( 4199 / 6 ) * x^10 + 0 * x^9 + ( -223193 / 140 ) * x^8 + 0 * x^7 + 2261 * x^6 + 0 * x^5 + ( -68723 / 40 ) * x^4 + 0 * x^3 + ( 43867 / 84 ) * x^2 + 0 * x^1 + 0

SUM of 1st term: 1
SUM of 2nd term: 524289
SUM of 3rd term: 1162785756
SUM of 10th term: 11506994510201251840
-------------------------------------------------------


In case you're not writing a polynomial class because you want to, but because you need one, you may find numpy's numpy.polynomial.Polynomial class useful: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html

Can you please update your question to include the code you run, exactly as you run it, to "compute coefficients for k = 17", and paste in the output you get, and the output you want to get?

You can't get the correct fraction from a float everytime, as most of them can't be represented exactly, so your numbers should never turn into floats at any point in your code if you are manipulating fractions. Why don't you use the well working and well tested fractions module of the standard library?

To answer everyone's comments, I implemented my own classes for the practice. And yes, you are right, technically it should never turn into a fraction at any point. So I'm not sure where the error is coming from. The coefficients are correct, I verified this, for some reason (either due to the Fraction class or the Polynomial class, the Polynomial.compute method isn't working accurately). I will update the post withe the output.

You could at least use fractions to verify that your own implementation is working correctly.

Instead of int(num / gcd) use the integer division operator: num // gcd. There may be cases where they get different results due to floating point roundoff errors.

Thank you, I used the fractions module to verify my output, the answers were correct when using the fractions module so that isolated the problem to my fractions implementation. I changed int(num/gcd) to num // gcd and that worked. Could you explain why that is the case? num / gcd should have always been an integer anyway.

The result of / is *always a float, even if it happens to be an integer value, and floats have limited precision. You'll get rounded numbers when your result gets large.
